# VBScript Can't write innerhtml to file

Tags: vbscript, innerhtml

Simply trying to grab innerhtml from this site and write to a text file.  I've never had this problem before and I can't seem to remedy it.  The innerhtml will echo perfectly, just can't actually write it to a text file.  Get "invalid procedure call or argument" error.  This script is super basic, but still getting errors...  Tried swapping with other URL's and works fine.  Something is happening specific to this site.  It's just a simple login screen and still can't get the innerhtml.  Any ideas?

```
set ie = createobject("internetexplorer.application") 
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\InstaGC_Dump.txt"

wscript.sleep 2000

ie.Visible = false
URL = "http://www.instagc.com" 

ie.navigate URL

'==============================
'wait until URL loads

do while ie.busy: wscript.sleep 100: loop
While IE.Busy: Wscript.Sleep 100: Wend
While IE.ReadyState <> 4: Wscript.Sleep 100: Wend
While IE.document.readystate <> "complete": wscript.sleep 100: Wend
wscript.sleep 2000 'Extra sleep to be safe
'==============================

pageText = ie.document.body.innerhtml

set ts = fso.opentextfile(filename,2,true) 
ts.write pageText
ts.close
```

TIA!

Comment: Try to open the text file as Unicode `set ts = fso.opentextfile(filename, 2, true, -1)`.

Comment: You are a genius.  Works!  I've never heard of this.  Can you explain why this works this way?  Also, not seeing an option to mark your comments as the solution.

Comment: A string containing unicode characters can not be saved to an ASCII text file properly, thus the error occurs. Read [OpenTextFile Method description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx).